# Ghost IO deployment to Production

Tags: ghost

I just setup ghost blog  and I start to use admin panel. when I want to change blog title and description  an error messagebox return to the screen and  it writes that  "The server returned an error (Server was not available)."

I also changed the config.js host to the IP of the website.

Comment: I just installed ghost for the first time a couple weeks ago. Here's what I have for the IP in my `config.s`: `127.0.0.1`

You're talking about the `config.js` in the ghost root directory?

Comment: Also, what's the web server and OS? I am on Centos 7 running nginx. It's pretty cool to use `pm2`. Here are some run forever instructions i just found that you might find use. I find pm2 to be very helpful.

https://perezbox.com/2014/12/configuring-ghost-5-on-centos-7/